# room update (or insert if not exist) rows and return count changed rows

Tags: android, android-room

I need update and if not exist insert row to ROOM DB.

I make this: `productRepository.updateProducts(productsResponse.getProductItems());`

And:

```
@Override
public void updateProducts(final List<ProductItem> products) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        for (ProductItem item : products) {
            Product product = createProduct(item);
            productDao.insert(product);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

And in DAO:

```
@Insert
void insert(Product products);
```

But I have method

```
@Update
void update(Product product);
```

And I have some questions:

1. both methods is void. How can I return saved Product or boolean flag or inserted count after insert?
2. if I try call `update` and I have not row will it be inserted?
3. How can I update(if not - insert) row and return count updatet or inserted rows?

Comment: you are looking for UPSERT  already  solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50736568/10516463

Answer (score 95):

As `@Danail Alexiev` said  `@Insert` can return a `long`. `@Update` can return an `int`.

But for what purpose are you using update? If you just want the whole object to be replaced by the new one then just specify the `OnConflictStrategy`

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insert(Product products);
```

**The result will be:** items that don't exist will be added, items that already exist will be replaced by the new ones.

In the case you need to **update just one param** (like quantity for example) you can do something like this

```
  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  void insert(Product products);

  @Query("SELECT * from item WHERE id= :id")
  List<Product> getItemById(int id);

  @Query("UPDATE item SET quantity = quantity + 1 WHERE id = :id")
  void updateQuantity(int id)

  void insertOrUpdate(Product item) {
                List<Product> itemsFromDB = getItemById(item.getId())
                if (itemsFromDB.isEmpty())
                    insert(item)
                else
                    updateQuantity(item.getId())   
            }
        }
```

**The result will be:** Try looking up the item in the DB, if found update a property, if not just insert a new item. So you only need to call one method `insertOrUpdate` from your DAO.

Comment: you're life saviour buddy .... I was just about to hate ROOM Db .. Thanks alot.

Comment: There are some problems with return types in the above code. Moreover, if there is no record for the query, the list should return empty, not null.

Comment: @Rainmaker my pleasure :)

Comment: To further optimise this, we can save the number of transactions performed on DB, by directly inserting with ConflictStrategy as Ignore and checking its return type. If insert fails since record exists it will directly update the record else insert successfully. So by this, extra looking up for the record in the DB is cancelled.

Comment: Be careful with this approach, because ConflictStrategy.REPLACE works like DELETE+INSERT. It means that all entities related with foreign key in other tables will be deleted ‍♂️

Answer (score 84):

1. A method, annotated with `@Insert` can return a `long`. This is the newly generated ID for the inserted row. A method, annotated with `@Update` can return an `int`. This is the number of updated rows.
2. `update` will try to update all your fields using the value of the primary key in a `where` clause. If your entity is not persisted in the database yet, the `update` query will not be able to find a row and will not update anything.
3. You can use `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)`. This will try to insert the entity and, if there is an existing row that has the same ID value, it will delete it and replace it with the entity you are trying to insert. Be aware that, if you are using auto generated IDs, this means that the the resulting row will have a different ID than the original that was replaced. If you want to preserve the ID, then you have to come up with a custom way to do it.

Comment: This is not a good solution. It does not perform an insert or update. this is a replacement so that you will lose fields you didn't specify for the update.

Comment: TL;DR Sqlite replace operation could violate onDelete foreignKey constraints but update doesn't. This do not cover the use case insertOrUpdate(), when you replace if you find the primary key on the table it deletes the row so that could suppose foreignKey violation that an update could handle OnCascade.

Answer (score 10):

UPDATE.

@Upsert added to Room 2.5.0-alpha03. No need for reinventing the wheel)

Thanks to @Ashwini for great idea.

```
@Dao
interface SendDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(model: DataModel): Long

    @Update
    suspend fun update(model: DataModel): Int

    @Transaction
    suspend fun insertOrUpdate(model: DataModel): Long {
        val id = insert(model)
        return if (id==-1L) {
            update(model)
            model.id
        } else {
            id
        }
    }
}
```

So we should call: `database.sendDao().insertOrUpdate(DataModel(...))`

Answer (score 8):

You can check your database if there is already item with specific field, for exmaple:

```
@Query("SELECT id FROM items WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1")
fun getItemId(id: String): String?

@Insert
fun insert(item: Item): Long

@Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun update(item: Item): Int
```

Item is Your object, and in your code:

```
 fun insertOrUpdate(item: Item) {
            database.runInTransaction {
                val id = getItemDao().getItemId(item.id)

                if(id == null)
                    getItemDao().insert(item)
                else
                    getItemDao().update(item)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you need to re-get the DAO everytime?

Comment: Just a semantics but shouldn't this better be `ItemDao` rather than `getItemDao`?

Answer (score 7):

You can do with @Upsert

```
def room_version = "2.5.0-beta01" // or later
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"


@Upsert(entity = Show::class)
fun updateOrInsert(shows: List<ShowUpdate>)

@Entity
data class Show(
@PrimaryKey var id: Int = 0,
val title: String? = null,
val imageUrl: String? = null,
val timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis(),
val isFavorite: Boolean? = false
)
```

This updates only some fields of Show. Does NOT update the field `isFavorite`

```
@Entity
data class ShowUpdate(
@PrimaryKey var id: Int = 0,
val title: String? = null,
val imageUrl: String? = null,
val timestamp: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check below method insertModel() where you can get onComplete() and onError() method:

```
    val db: AppDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(mCtx, AppDatabase::class.java, "db_nam.sqlite").build()

    companion object {
        @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
        private var mInstance: DatabaseClient? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(mCtx: Context): DatabaseClient {
            if (mInstance == null) {
                mInstance = DatabaseClient(mCtx)
            }
            return mInstance as DatabaseClient
        }
    }

    // SEE HERE FOR INSERTING DATA SUCCESSFULLY AND ERROR CODE  
    private fun insertModel(rss_Model: RSS_Model) {
        Completable.fromAction {

            db.database_dao().insertRSS(rss_Model)

        }.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(object : CompletableObserver {
                    override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {}

                    override fun onComplete() {
                        // Log.e("onComplete","GET SUCCESS HERE")
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                        // Log.e("onError","onError")
                    }
                })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM pojo WHERE pojo.id = :id")
Maybe<POJO> checkPOJO(String id);
```

you can insertOrUpdate like this:

```
checkPOJO(id).toSingle().concatMapCompletable(pojo->update(pojo))
   .onErrorResumeNext(t -> t instanceof NoSuchElementException ? 
   insert(...): Completable.error(t));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `INSERT OR REPLACE` in the Room ORM, i wrote a query for my self and it work, write like my query :

```
@Query(
    "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO VolumeManagement (id, max_volume, min_volume, stream_type, id_user) " +
            "VALUES ((SELECT id FROM VolumeManagement WHERE id_user = :userId AND stream_type = :streamType)," +
            " :newMaxVolume, :newMinVolume, :streamType, :userId)"
)
suspend fun updateOrInsertVolume(newMaxVolume: Int, newMinVolume: Int, streamType: Int, userId: String): Long
```

consider that my userId and streamType are unique

Answer (score -4):

You also can check if the entry exists in the database or not you can make your logic accordingly

**Kotlin**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE productId == :id")
fun isProductExist(id: Int): Boolean
```

**Java**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE productId == :id")
public boolean isExist(int id);
```

Answer (score -11):

You should use Rx Android ***Single*** to solve this problem. Example:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM subjectFormTable WHERE study_subject_id ==:subjectFormId")
fun getSubjectForm(subjectFormId: Int): Single<SubjectFormEntity>
```

We use

```
val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
```

And

```
compositeDisposable.add(
            subjectFormDao.getSubjectForm(studySubjectId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                Log.e(TAG, "successful ")
            }, {
                Log.e(TAG, "error "+it.message)
                //Insert or Update data here
            })
    )
```