# how to achieve sqlite query in room database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

This is SQLite query i want to use in room database
here is the first to try insert data and if data is already exist then update the data by using id

```
INSERT INTO books(id, title, author, year_published)  VALUES(@id, @title, @author, @year_published)
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title = @title,  author = @author;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519896/room-update-or-insert-if-not-exist-rows-and-return-count-changed-rows

Comment: @Raghunandan i want only update two filed

Comment: not sure but you can insert or update if the values exist. check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RawQuery if it helps

Comment: By using `@Query(<your-query-here>)`

Comment: @AnujSharma on duplicate not found in *roomdatabase*

Comment: @Parth - have you tried this as well - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RawQuery

Answer (score 0):

Room supports @RawQuery annotation to construct queries at run-time. So you need:

```
@Dao
interface BooksDao{
    @RawQuery
    List<Book> books(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
}
```

And create your query in old school style:

```
String queryString = "here is your query";
List<Object> args = new ArrayList(); // here is your args for your query
```

And ther performe your query:

```
SimpleSQLiteQuery query = new SimpleSQLiteQuery(queryString, args.toArray());
List<Book> result = booksDao.books(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with **OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE**

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertBooks(vararg books: Book)
```

And you have to specify the id **id** as **primary key**

```
@Entity(tableName = "book_table")
data class Book(
    @PrimaryKey val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val author: String,
    val year_published: Int
)
```